# boost program options: argument being detected more than once

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, command-line-interface

Following code detects the arguments being specified more than once.

The command line arguments parser is implemented to ensure that the user provides a `string (mps-file)`, `integer (n)` and a `sequence of integer (0, n-1)` allowing others to be optional.

However, when the code is compiled using the following flags:
`g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp /home/not_me/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib/libboost_program_options.so`

Which compiles perfectly. But when executed in the following way it throws the following exception.

```
/src/a.out --mps-file earth.mps --n 5 --size 10 --seed 10 --order 0 1 2 3 4
error: option '--mps-file' cannot be specified more than once
```

But if executed using the following command it runs fine:
`./src/a.out earth.mps 5 10 10 --order 0 1 2 3 4`

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int n;
    int sample_size = 10;
    std::random_device rd;
    int seed = rd();
    std::string mps_name;
    std::vector<int> order;

    boost::program_options::options_description desc("options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("mps-file", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(&mps_name)->required(), "input mps file")
        ("n", boost::program_options::value<int>(&n)->required(), "number of variables")
        ("size", boost::program_options::value<int>(&sample_size)->default_value(sample_size), "size of sample")
        ("seed", boost::program_options::value<int>(&seed)->default_value(seed), "seed value")
        ("order", boost::program_options::value<std::vector<int>>(&order)->required(), "ordering")
        ("help", "this help message")
        ;

    boost::program_options::positional_options_description p;
    p.add("mps-file", 1);
    p.add("n", 1);
    p.add("order", -1);

    boost::program_options::variables_map vm;

    try {
        boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::command_line_parser(argc, argv).
                                      options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);

        if (vm.count("help") || argc == 1) {
            std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " [options]" << std::endl;
            std::cout << desc;
            return -1;
        }

        boost::program_options::notify(vm);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<int> temp = order;
    std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (temp[i] == i) { continue; }
        std::cout << "incorrect ordering given" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (n != order.size()) {
        std::cout << "mismatch between the 'n' and given ordering" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: @MarkB I tried that as well. Got rid of the positional arguments  (by commenting `p.add()`) and the issue still persisted.

Comment: `libboost_program_options.s`? .s files are assembler source code - it seems very weird to me you assembler file to the `gcc`...

Comment: @MarkB positional arguments _require_ the named option description to exist in Boost Program Options

Comment: @MarkB `libboost_program_options.so` it was a typo. fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the positional options. When you remove them and the `positional(p)` call from `boost::program_options::command_line_parser(argc, argv).
            options(desc).positional(p).run()` 
your problem will be gone. Since you only removed `add()` lines and left `positional(p)`, you got a different problem: "too many positional options have been specified on the command line".

I suppose that the problem with your call:

`/src/a.out --mps-file earth.mps --n 5 --size 10 --seed 10 --order 0 1 2 3 4`

is that when there is a positional option defined on position 1, then the string `---mps-file` may be considered a value of this option itself. So you should probably avoid passing options with names, if the options were defined as positional.

Comment: @letsBeePolite What exactly didn't work for you? What kind of error you get when you leave just: ```boost::program_options::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).run()```?